# ruby sqlite3 insert with autoincrement

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I have a trouble inserting data into a sqlite3 database with an id autoincrement. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
begin
    db = SQLite3::Database.open db_name
    db.execute "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Audit(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        module TEXT,
        hostname TEXT,
        criticity TEXT,
        raw_data TEXT
    );"
rescue SQLite3::Exception => e
    puts e.backtrace
ensure
    db.close if db
end
```

And I insert data like this:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO Audit VALUES (module,hostname,criticity,raw_data)", 
    check,
    hostname,
    raw_data,
    criticity
)
```

Here is the error:

```
#<SQLite3::SQLException: table Audit has 5 columns but 4 values were supplied>
```

I don't know how to supply the `id` values as it should be auto-incremented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an odd error I get `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: module`
I think you have the wrong format you could do this format try,

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO Audit (module,hostname,criticity,raw_data) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ", 'module', 'host', 'criticity', "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01")
```

Results:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM Audit;
1|module|host|criticity|☺
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as guess try insert null value.

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO Audit VALUES (id, module,hostname,criticity,raw_data)", 
    null,
    check,
    hostname,
    raw_data,
    criticity
)
```

Also look at  https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1 it states a `A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement`